# Is there a way to get LIKE operator on data in stackmob

Tags: stackmob

I have a Search UseCase on user list . How can i use Stackmob in such scenarios? i dont think i can use IN , Any Suggestions? How can i retrieve all Users having Similar Name LIKE JOHN or JOHNSON  from a User Schema. Does StackMob provide LIKE kind of operator in SQL over a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work at StackMob...

The IN operator is your best option currently, but we are looking at adding full text search in the near future. The reason we don't expose LIKE or REGEX queries is because they are not very performant and often result in full collection/table scans. That being the case, and wanting to provide only services that scale, we are looking into more robust solutions like full text search.